# Java BigInteger in bash; rewrite gradlew

Tags: java, linux, gradle

I am trying to rewrite gradle's wrapper so it doesn't depend on a binary. I am forced to do this since Apache doesn't allow binaries in the source.  I have most of it done, but the way that gradle generates its hash for a distro is problematic for me.  The code is below.

Does anyone know how to redo this in just bash?

```
/**
 * This method computes a hash of the provided {@code string}.
 * <p>
 * The algorithm in use by this method is as follows:
 * <ol>
 *    <li>Compute the MD5 value of {@code string}.</li>
 *    <li>Truncate leading zeros (i.e., treat the MD5 value as a number).</li>
 *    <li>Convert to base 36 (the characters {@code 0-9a-z}).</li>
 * </ol>
 */
private String getHash(String string) {
    try {
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] bytes = string.getBytes();
        messageDigest.update(bytes);
        return new BigInteger(1, messageDigest.digest()).toString(36);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not hash input string.", e);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I should also be fine if I can implement this on any other scripting language thats there by default on mac/linux.  So if you can do this in python without installing packages, should be fine as well.

EDIT 2:

For right now, I am doing just a MD5 hash of the URL and replacing all the logic that gradle-wrapper.jar did with the following script: https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12678654/BIGTOP-1384.3.patch.

Would be great if I can replace the hash logic to match without requiring things installed already.

Comment: Isn't gradlew already open source?

Comment: Its open source.  The issue is that to use the gradle wrapper requires a project to include a binary gradle-wrapper.jar.  This is not allowed in Apache; only source is allowed.

Comment: We also want to make it simple for people to build.  doing ./gradlew should just work even with apache's limitation on binary.

Comment: Are you sure such a limitation exists?  Literally the first place I looked, there's binaries in the repo: https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=ant.git;a=tree;f=lib/optional;h=ced406f50356a862a2dd86ebb8136d7c30217e4e;hb=HEAD

Comment: Im being told that we are still not allowed to and that I can not add the binaries into the project.  Adding the binary into the project won't be allowed by any PMC member.

Comment: Also, are you saying that you're trying to replicate all of [this](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/subprojects/wrapper/src/main/java/org/gradle/wrapper) in Bash?

Comment: bash or python/ruby as long as its zero dependencies on mac/linux.

Comment: @ekaqu is right. You can just add `gradlew` and the binary wrapper will be download if not cached. There's no need to rewrite it.

Comment: @Opal: That's not right; the wrapper is what downloads *everything else*.  `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar` is part of the wrapper.

Comment: Yes of course, sorry the bad comment. Maybe just implement downloading the wrapper?

Comment: Updated the above to link to my patch.  What it does is replace all the logic that the gradle-wrapper.jar did.  The only difference is the hashing that is used.  Not sure how to get it to match without requiring a user install a binary, so doing just a basic md5 hash now.  Would love to replace the hash logic to match.